# How to query tables in EF by string name of table?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to write what seems to me a simple scenario. In most of our applications, we have a system for allowing the user to edit the values of drop-downs -- lookup tables.

The drop-down tables are typically very small, consisting of just a few fields:

- id (PK, int identity 1,1)
- Description (nvarchar)
- LastModifiedBy (nvarchar)
- LastModifiedDate (smalldatetime)

They *may* have additional fields, which obviously would differ from table to table. The id, LastModifiedBy and LastModifiedDate properties are all defined in a base entity class from which all our other entities derive.

We need to be able to query an EF context for an entity which -- aside from three common fields -- is completely unknown (both its name/type and fields) until runtime. This negates generics, which are otherwise wonderful. We are able to solve a lot of the reflection problems on our own -- this will handle the unknown columns, as we can enumerate our properties and go from there. The harder problem we're seeing is trying to query EF, and get a serializable entity back, when we don't know the table until runtime.

So I suppose the simplest way to ask this is: How can I query EF, and get a serializable entity back from it, using a string name for the entity?

What we're looking to implement is a method whose signature looks something like this:

```
public BaseEntity RetrieveEntity(string entityType, int? id);
```

Once we have that core in place, we should be able to easily adapt it to our other scenarios (insert, update, retrieve a paged list for the grid, etc).

Just so we have something concrete to work with, we can use the table definition above. We'll call the entity `StatusCode`, and assume its definition is as follows:

```
public partial class StatusCode : BaseEntity // BaseEntity gives us id, LastModifiedBy, LastModifiedDate
{
    public string StatusCodeDescription { get; set; }
}

public class StatusCodeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<StatusCode>
{
    // boilerplate comments removed for brevity
    this.HasKey(t => t.id);

    this.Property(t => t.StatusCodeDescription)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(255);

    this.ToTable("StatusCode");
    this.Property(t => t.id).HasColumnName("StatusCodeId");
    this.Property(t => t.StatusCodeDescription).HasColumnName("StatusCodeDescription");
    this.Property(t => t.LastModifiedBy).HasColumnName("LastModifiedBy");
    this.Property(t => t.LastModifiedDate).HasColumnName("LastModifiedDate");
}
```

**IF** I could categorically state that all the drop downs would have a description, and nothing else, then I could just create an abstract class from which the drop-downs derive and deal with that. I'd still have to be able to query dynamically by name and retrieve an instance of that object, though. And truthfully, I cannot guarantee that this is the case. Some of these *will* have other fields -- a boolean property here or there, maybe a code mapped to the description for use in back-end integration, etc. So just using a base class is not the solution, and won't fully play.

PS: I'm certain this is actually a dupe. I know I can't be the first to have this issue. I'm very happy to close it if we can find the solution elsewhere on SO. However, I've spent the entire afternoon on Google trying to find a holistic solution to this problem, and have failed miserably. That said, my Google-Fu is probably failing me today.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19259299/139917

Comment: @DaveB: Thanks, I think some of the approaches there probably will.

Answer (score 1):

You say you have a `BaseEntity` class and all these classes inherit from it.

What type of inheritance are you using? [TPH?](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx)

Have you added a `public DbSet<BaseEntity> BaseEntities { get; set; }` to the context?

I'm pretty sure if you do that then your method can be implemented like this:

```
public BaseEntity RetrieveEntity(string entityType, int? id)
{
   var e = context.BaseEntities.Find(id.GetValueOrDefault(-1));
   if(e.GetType() != entityType)
      return null;

   return e;
}
```

Not sure why you'd want to do that though. I'd have this:

```
public BaseEntity RetrieveEntity(int id)
{     
   return context.BaseEntities.Find(id);
}
```

and use it like this

```
StatusCode sc = RetrieveEntity(int id) as StatusCode;
if(sc != null)
   //etc
```

or this:

```
public T RetrieveEntity<T>(int id) where T: BaseEntity
{
   return context.BaseEntities.Find(id) as T
}
```

and use it like this:

```
StatusCode sc = RetrieveEntity<StatusCode>(int id)
if(sc != null)
   //etc
```

**edit** or you could just use the generic DbSet like this

```
public T RetrieveEntity<T>(int id) where T: BaseEntity
{
   return context.DbSet<T>().Find(id)
}
```

Comment: This feels like it's not quite going to play. I mean, yes, I can adapt this to work in a list, but I'm not seeing how a DbSet of the base class (which doesn't, in and of itself, correspond to a table anywhere) will actually play out. EF will have to convert whatever we do to a SQL query hitting a table -- and it will need to know which table to hit. Maybe I'm just missing something here?

Comment: The above comment notwithstanding, while I don't think you had my answer, you *did* have the most important piece of what is becoming my answer: You provided the link to the TPH article. Although we are not using a true TPH approach, that showed me how to construct the entity SQL in such a way that we were able to get our objects ... And everything seems so *nice* already. Light at the end of the tunnel, thank you!

Comment: No table means not TPH then. Have you looked at TPC? http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx but that's probably overkill. Could you not just use the generic DbSet? See my edit

Comment: The generic doesn't play because we don't get the entity type until runtime. Using OFTYPE in Entity SQL worked like a champ. For data inserts and updates, we used a little reflection. So far, all are working. Hopefully I'll remember the bounty I'd planned on awarding for pointing me in the direction I needed.

Comment: I guess I've not quite understood your problem. I'd be interested in seeing your solution though. Perhaps you could post your own answer?

Comment: Hoping to eventually. Not sure if I technically can; it does belong to the client.