# entity framework access table by string

Tags: c#, mysql, string, entity-framework, webapi

I have written a code like this and it works fine .

```
        List<lbmaster> l1 = new List<lbmaster>();
        int str123 = 2;
        string nam;
        using (MockContext Db = new MockContext())
        {
            
            l1=Db.lb_master.Where(_ => _.id==str123)
                .ToList();
             nam= l1[0].tablename;
        }
         using (var Db1 = new MockContext())
        {
            switch (nam)
            {
                case "Users": return Db1.Users.ToList();
                              break;
                 case "lb_master": return Db1.lb_master.ToList();
                              break;
            }
         }
```

But i want to write a code in such a way that i don't have to use switch case,
instead I just use the "nam" variable which contains the table name as string and through that i want to access the table

eg : Db1.nam.ToList();

Is there any way to achieve this, coz i've tried [Get table by name with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030910/get-table-by-name-with-entity-framework?answertab=active#tab-top)  and others but am not able to achieve this.

Context name : MockContext
table names : "Users" and "lb_master"
lb_master contains the list of other tables name
so i'm fetching the tabel name from lb_master and from that string wanna access the table

Is it possible to achieve this?

thank You!!